# Two list count in python

Tags: python-3.x, list

I use python3.6 
I have two lists , and I want to take  first list zero roll to scan my data, 
if it have in data it add one.
like this :

```
first list:
['I1', 'I2', 'I3']
['I1', 'I2', 'I5']
['I1', 'I2', 'I4']
['I1', 'I3', 'I5']
['I1', 'I2', 'I3', 'I4']
['I1', 'I2', 'I3', 'I5']
['I1', 'I2', 'I4', 'I5']
['I2', 'I3', 'I4']
['I2', 'I3', 'I5']
['I2', 'I4', 'I5']
```

second list:

```
[['I1', 'I2', 'I5'], 
['I2', 'I4'], 
['I2', 'I3'], 
['I1', 'I2', 'I4'], 
['I1', 'I3'], 
['I2', 'I3'], 
['I1', 'I3'], 
['I1', 'I2', 'I3', 'I5'], 
['I1', 'I2', 'I3']]
```

I take fist list to scan second list and it appear in second list twice , so is count is two.

```
['I1', 'I2', 'I3']:2
['I1', 'I2', 'I5']:2
['I1', 'I2', 'I4']:1
['I1', 'I3', 'I5']:1
['I1', 'I2', 'I3', 'I4']:0
['I1', 'I2', 'I3', 'I5']:1
['I1', 'I2', 'I4', 'I5']:0
['I2', 'I3', 'I4']:0
['I2', 'I3', 'I5']:1
['I2', 'I4', 'I5']:0
```

How can I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Takes into account the fact that first_list can be a subset of an item in second_list:

```
count = 0
for item in second_list:
    if all(elt in item for elt in first_list):
        count += 1
```

Comment: But my second list number seven roll have I1,I2,I3

Comment: Oh I see, you mean we should count the first_list even if it is only a subset of an item in the second_list

Comment: yeah! how can i do?

Comment: but I print is all zero.